# How to display apriori algorithm dataframe in flask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, flask

I make recommendations using the apriori algorithm, the results of the apriori algorithm are stored in the dataframe in the result variable. in Result there are 3 columns, namely the rule, support and confidence columns.  Like below

```
Result=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Rule','Support','Confidence'])
for idx, elem in enumerate(association_results):
  # print(elem)
        thiselem = elem
        # print("1 ", thiselem)
        nextelem = association_results[(idx + 1) % len(association_results)]
        # r1 = [x for x in thiselem[0]]
        # r2 = [x for x in nextelem[0]]
        # print("rule: ", r1[0], r2[0])
        # print("sup: ", elem[1])
        # print("conf: ", elem[2][0][2])
        Result=Result.append({
            'Rule':str([str(x) for x in thiselem[0]])+ " -> " +str([str(x) for x in nextelem[0]]),
            'Support':str(round(elem[1] *100, 2))+'%',
            'Confidence':str(round(elem[2][0][2] *100, 2))+'%'
            },ignore_index=True)
```

I display the result of the dataframe in flask, this is the route

```
@app.route('/rekomendasi', methods=['POST'])
def rekomendasi():
    sup = request.form.get('support')
    conf = request.form.get('confidence')

    # Model
    store_data = pd.read_csv('dataPekerjaan.csv', sep=',', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
    records = []
    # memisahkan data menjadi list
    for i in range(store_data.shape[0]):
        records.append([str(store_data.values[i, j]).split(',') for j in range(store_data.shape[1])])

    # hanya ambil data nama pekerjaan
    dataKerja = [[] for dataKerja in range(len(records))]
    for i in range(len(records)):
        for j in records[i][1]:
            dataKerja[i].append(j)
    # dataKerja

    min_sup = float('0.00' + str(sup))

    min_conf = float('0.00' + str(conf))

    association_rules = apriori(dataKerja, min_support=min_sup, min_confidence=min_conf, min_length=2)
    association_results = list(association_rules)

    # menampilkan hasil asosiasi
    pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 200)
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Rule', 'Support', 'Confidence'])

    for item in association_results:
        pair = item[2]
        for i in pair:
            result = result.append({
                'Rule': str([x for x in i[0]]) + " -> " + str([x for x in i[1]]),
                'Support': str(round(item[1] * 100, 2)) + '%',
                'Confidence': str(round(i[2] * 100, 2)) + '%'
            }, ignore_index=True)

    return render_template('rekomendasi.html', name='made', sup = sup, conf = conf, len= len(result)-1,  query = result)
```

and this is the rekomendasi.html

```
{%for i in range(len) %}
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{i+1}}</th>
                        <td>{{query['Rule'][i]}}</td>
                        <td>{{query['Support'][i]}}</td>
                        <td>{{query['Confidence'][i]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  {%endfor%}
```

I wanted it to look like this without the [' '] in Rule column
[image]

But when the flask is run, this is how it looks like.
[image]

Is there anyway to fix this

Comment: Do you only want to remove the single quotes or both single quotes and square brackets?

Comment: @Ashyam i want the both single quotes and square brackets to be remove, do you know how to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `join` function to join items in a list with delimiter. Here the delimiter is `,` . So your code will be:

```py
...

for item in association_results:
    pair = item[2]
    for i in pair:
        result = result.append({
            'Rule': ", ".join([x for x in i[0]]) + " -> " + ", ".join([x for x in i[1]]),
            'Support': str(round(item[1] * 100, 2)) + '%',
            'Confidence': str(round(i[2] * 100, 2)) + '%'
        }, ignore_index=True)

...
```

This should replace the quotes and the brackets